# Increasing domains reaching the whole space with Zorn

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:K\to\Bbb R^n$ be continuous, with $K$ compact in $\Bbb R^m$.

$f$ joins the following property:

> There exists $U_1$ relatively compact nhbd of $K$ with $\operatorname{dist}(K,\Bbb R^n\setminus U_1)>0$, such that $f$ continuously extends to $\overline U_1$.
> Now $f:\overline U_1\to\Bbb R^n$ is continuous and ​we can reiterate the same procedure on $U_2$ a relatively compact nhbd of $\overline U_1$.

The above property can be iterated to get an increasing sequence
$$
U_1\subset\cdots\subset\bigcup_jU_j=:\widetilde U\subseteq\Bbb R^m
$$
along with the distances
$$
d_j:=\operatorname{dist}(\overline {U_j},\Bbb R^m\setminus \overline {U_{j+1}})\;.
$$

On one hand it seems natural to obtain $\widetilde U=\Bbb R^m$, on the other I don't have control on the $d_j$s so they can go to zero super fast preventing $\widetilde U$ from being $\Bbb R^m$. But in this latter case we can repeat the procedure again obtaining in the end a $U'$ bigger than $\widetilde U$, and repeating countably many times I can approach again to something which is NOT the whole $\Bbb R^m$.

But in principle I could continue a continuum number of times, which should allow me to reach $\Bbb R^m$, maybe exploiting Zorn?

Or is it maybe something trivial, like arguing by contradiction: if $f$ extends to a maximal compact $L$, then its property guarantees a continuous extension to a strictly bigger domain.
But sounds uhm.

Can somebody shade a light?

Comment: Your $\widetilde U\ne \Bbb R^n$ may be relatively compact, it may not, but ultimately I don't understand what the purpose is of all that jazz. You have a continuous function $f:K\to\Bbb R^m$, with $K\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ compact and you want what?

Comment: Understand if the maximal domain to which such an $f$ satisfying the given "local extension property", is always the whole $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you’re actually assuming that $f$ has the following very strong property: if $L\subseteq\Bbb R^m$ is compact, $K\subseteq\operatorname{int}L$, and $g:L\to\Bbb R^n$ is a continuous extension of $f$, then $L$ has a bounded open nbhd $U$ to which $g$ can be continuously extended. Is that correect?

Comment: Even stronger I think: $f:K\to\Bbb R^n$ is given continuous. Then there exists $L\subset\Bbb R^n$ compact such that $f$ extends continuously on $L$ AND the same pattern repeats: there exists a bigger compact (or equivalently a relatively compact neighborhood) such that the function extends to it and so on.

Comment: @Joe: That doesn’t add anything to what I required.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: that was confusing, my apologies. I have edited my question, I hope it's now clearer.

Comment: @Joe: I understood it. My condition is precisely what you require and avoids the *and so on* nature of your description.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: you wrote "IF an extension exists, then it can be further extended", but we need also to add that "a first extension exists". Do you agree?

Comment: @Joe: Yes, you’re right: I should have included that. I was actually taking it for granted, since I was concentrating on pinning down exactly what is needed to iterate extensions.

Comment: Probably wrong argument but maybe worth to be shared: if we assume to consider at each step the maximal $U_{j+1}$ containing $U_j$, then it means that already at step 1 we wouldn't be allowed to continue to step 2, otherwise $U_2$ would be bigger than the maximal $U_1$. But this doesn't sound correct, since $U_{2}$ is the maximal extension of $f:\overline{U_1}\to\Bbb R^m$, NOT of $f:K\to\Bbb R^m$ which are two different objects.